# Allowing users 'Follow on Instagram' from my app (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I want to connect users' Instagram accounts to my app, and be able to make them follow other users (that s/he chooses) on Instagram; or at least triggering the Instagram app and go to users' profile. I am currently using Swift and the documentations out there are not so clear. Is it actually possible to do what I want to do? If so, how can I do it? Thanks in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will do the job:

if instagram app is not installed, then it will open the webpage of instagram in safari.
If the app is installed, it opens the page you want in instagram app:)

```
func openInstagram() {


    var instURL: NSURL = NSURL (string: "instagram://user?username=Instagram")! // Replace = Instagram by the your instagram user name
    var instWB: NSURL = NSURL (string: "https://instagram.com/instagram/")! // Replace the link by your instagram weblink

    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instURL)) {
        // Open Instagram application
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instURL)
    } else {
        // Open in Safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instWB)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is document page from Instagram for ios developers (you can find how to open user Instagram profile): https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Library that may help you (connect user accounts, follow): https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit

Comment: Any idea for swift? Maybe a tutorial or documentation?

Comment: @senty It's the same for Swift.  Just syntax difference.  I use this library for my project in Swift.

Comment: @senty I remember I had some difficulties to convert login demo into Swift, so I kept the connect user function as in Objective-C. But the rest of the functions in Swift.  I am not sure if they have made changes to adapt to Swift completely.

Comment: @Liu I digged into the InstagramKit, and its working fine. However, after successfully logging in, when you click on a picture; 'Test' button is the follow button, am I right? When I click on the Test button, I get [This in the logs.](http://notepad.cc/sentyinsta) Do you have any idea? :)

Comment: @senty Eh,, I guess you have to show me code so I can know which button :)  Looks like an error that you didn't provide correct parameters.